# Cannot open WPF solution with VS Express for Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio

I'm new to Windows.
I have source code of WPF Application, which I want to submit to windows store, but when I try to open it using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows, it says: "This project is incompatible with the current edition".

Also, there is no WPF Application option under "New project".

How can I open my WPF Application and submit it to windows store?

Comment: Two questions : Are you on windows 8+ ? When you installed Visual Studio 2013, did you install the optional component "Maintenance tools for Windows Store Applications" (the name may not be exactly the same, I'm in a different locale) ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Windows 8, where do I look if I have installed the Maintanence tools?

Comment: It depends on which edition of Express you have... one is for Windows 8 apps (xaml or JavaScript) and the other will do WPF, Windows Forms, etc.  As far as I know, you do not submit WPF apps to the store... only Windows 8 apps.

Comment: Wow forgot that one...

My bad, i did not see you were using the express edition.... My second question was for another edition of VS 2013

Comment: You should use Visual Studio 2013 Community - there you can work with WPF and Store Apps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WPF Application is not compatible with Windows Store.
You must create a Windows Store App which you can find in Universal App section of the Project templates.